# Python: 'for ... in' statement evaluation behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have following code sample in python:

```
def get_objects():
    print 'Called get_objects'
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]       


def main():
    for i in get_objects():
        print i

main()
```

Output for this as following:

```
Called get_objects
1
2
3
4
5
```

So my question is why get_objects() called only once? Why it is not fetched data every time of itteration?

Comment: `get_objects()` is called only once and then its return value (a list) is used for the loop.

Comment: Ok I understand what code doing now. I am asking why?

Comment: Turn the why question back on yourself - why would the for loop ever terminate if it called get_objects() every time?

Comment: @wim Through the c++ I knew that using objects.length in for loop is not good idea. Because it is fetched every time is this behavior is not true for python for loops?

Comment: It is not like a c++ for loop, it is more like a [foreach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) loop.

Comment: Following up on @wim: What would you _expect_ this to print? `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` over and over? `1`, then `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `1`, `2`, `3`, … forever? Or something different?

Comment: @wim you can down vote but it not meter. I am learning and getting information. I am new at python. So do not be angry I am comparing two language futures. Sorry if I not state my thoughts clearly.

Comment: @abarnert yeah I thought [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] over and over.   I didn't downvote you Phoenix.

Comment: @Phoenix: I don't think wim is getting angry at you, he's trying to help clarify things in hopes that you will understand better.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry I expect iterating through 5 elements. But I do not knew behavior of this. Sorry

Comment: @downvoter leave a comment at least it improves my skills in future.

Comment: @Phoenix: If you're used to C++, have you used the range-based for loop syntax added in C++11, `for (int i: get_objects())`? If so… Python's loop works almost exactly the same as that. If not, [here's a blog post explaining them](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html).

Comment: (P.S., the "almost" is because a C++ `range` and a Python `iterable` are different in many ways, so various cases are expressed a little differently or have different edge cases. But the intuitive idea is the same in both cases.)

Comment: No, sorry I put `c++` actually I used `c` under linux environment. So for loop behavior is different. Now it is clear to me what is going on. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45237/discussion-between-abarnert-and-phoenix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that is exactly how for-loops work in Python.  The expression on the right of the `in` operator (which must return an iterable when evaluated) is evaluated only *once*, before looping commences. Then, the for-loop loops over the iterable returned by that evaluation.

Below is an excerpt from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)*:

> The for statement is used to iterate over the elements of a sequence
>   (such as a string, tuple or list) or other iterable object:
>
> ```
> for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
>               ["else" ":" suite]
> ```
>
> **The expression list is evaluated once**; it should yield an iterable
>   object.

---

*Note:  I added the bold.

Comment: Can you give some documentation related source or some reference for the book.

Comment: Through the `c++` I knew that using objects.length in for loop is not good idea. Because it is fetched every time is this behavior is not true for python for loops?

Comment: @Phoenix - Here's a documentation link: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement